# Error while trying to run standard deviation function

Tags: r, standard-deviation

I am trying to run:

```
testing_obj <- sd('1', '2', '3', '4', '5')
```

in R. When I run the function it throws the error:

> Error in sd(1, 2, 3, 4, 5) : unused arguments (3, 4, 5).

Why is that happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sd` operates on a *vector*, i.e. it takes a single argument that is a numeric vector. You are passing it multiple arguments. Use `c()` to combine your values into a single vector:

```
sd(c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5))
```

or more compactly `sd(1:5)` in this case ...

Comment: Sure professor, I already check marked it. Thank you for your answer, and it solved my problem.